# MySQL - retrieving different data from a table in the same select query

Tags: mysql

I've been using Stack Overflow for years but this is the first time I've not been able to find the answer.

I'm attempting to build a query within MySQL using 4 tables

**name**, **user**, **admin**, **actions**

the **actions** table has **actions_id**, **admin_id**, **user_id** and **action** columns

the **user** table has **user_id** and **name_id** columns

the **admin** table has **admin_id** and **name_id** columns

the **name** table has **name_id**,  **first_name** and **_last_name** columns

what I'd like to do is show the contents of **actions** replacing the **user_id** and **admin_id** with the **first_name** and **last_name** for the linking **name_id** via **admin** and **user**

Comment: Please add your query attempt; surely you have tried something.

Comment: SELECT * FROM 
actions, user, admin, NAME
WHERE actions.`user_id` = user.`user_id`
AND actions.`admin_id` = admin.`admin_id`
AND name.`name_id` = user.`name_id`;

If I try and add anything to do linking the name table to the admin.name_id I get issues with query

Answer (score 0):

you have to use  `join`  to relate all tables together

```
select t1.action,n.first_name as user_FirstName,n.last_name as user_LastName,
    n1.first_name as adminFirstname,n1.last_name as AdminLastName from 
    (
    select a.action,ad.name_id as adnameid,u.name_id as unameid from actions  a inner join user  u on a.user_id=u.user_id
    inner join admin  ad on a.admin_id =ad.admin_id 
    ) as t1 inner join name  n on t1.unameid =n.name_id
    inner join name n1 on t1.adnameid=n1.name_id
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, although I had to add a from between  unameid  and actions

Is there anyway to show the rest of the columns in the actions table?

Comment: @DaB00m yes there is a way just have to select those columns

Comment: How? I trying using * instead or adding the specific columns in but it didn't work

select t1.action,n.first_name as user_FirstName,n.last_name as user_LastName,
    n1.first_name as adminFirstname,n1.last_name as AdminLastName from 
    (
    select a.action,ad.name_id as adnameid,u.name_id as unameid from actions  a inner join user  u on a.user_id=u.user_id
    inner join admin  ad on a.admin_id =ad.admin_id 
    ) as t1 inner join name  n on t1.unameid =n.name_id
    inner join name n1 on t1.adnameid=n1.name_id

Comment: @DaB00m can you please show me your problem  where you faced obstacle? or you can create your table and data http://sqlfiddle.com this link and i will help you according to that